# How to copy html elements from Chrome DevTools

Tags: html, macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

On the recent version of Chrome for Mac, I can't copy HTML from devtools 'Elements' Tab. Instead of a right-click menu giving me the option to 'copy', I'm getting a right-click menu 'Speech'.

How can I copy HTML Elements with this version of Chrome ?

Version 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this has changed; I'm running Chrome 77 on OSX:

- <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>
- Select the `Elements` tab
- Select a node
- Right-click and select `Copy` (a sub-menu shows up with different copy options)

[image]